# BigQuery WHERE key NOT IN mismatch?

Tags: google-bigquery

How is this possible?

```
SELECT DISTINCT key FROM dataset.first_table 
-- 5,026,143

SELECT DISTINCT key FROM dataset.first_table 
WHERE key IN (SELECT key FROM dataset.second_table)
-- 2,630,635

SELECT DISTINCT key FROM dataset.first_table 
WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM dataset.second_table)
-- 0
```

How can the last statement return no results?

I don't know what to add here. I guess it's just some kind of weird syntax mistake.
I'm sure that `second_table` does not contain all `key`s from the `first_table`:

```
SELECT key FROM dataset.first_table LIMIT 1
-- "a"

SELECT key FROM dataset.second_table WHERE key = "a"
-- no results
```

Also:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key FROM dataset.first_table
LEFT JOIN dataset.second_table USING (key)
WHERE second_table.key IS NULL
-- 2,395,612
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `key` column in your `dataset.second_table` has `null` values.

Would you try below and see if it works ?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT key FROM dataset.first_table 
 WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM dataset.second_table WHERE key IS NOT NULL);
```

- [Semantic rules of IN operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#in_operators) :

  *When using the `NOT IN` operator, the following semantics apply in this order:*

  - Returns TRUE if value_set is empty.
  - Returns NULL if search_value is NULL.
  - Returns FALSE if value_set contains a value equal to search_value.
  - **Returns NULL if value_set contains a NULL.**
  - Returns TRUE.

[image]

Comment: Yep, thats the case. What's the reasoning behind this? Why NULLs are matched to everything?

Comment: you can think `key not in('a', null)` as a shorthand of `key != 'a' AND key != null` and the result of `x AND y` is *true* only if both *x* and *y* evaluate to *true*. The problem here is that comparing some value with `null` is not  defined, so `key != null` always evalute to *null* and `null AND true` also becomes *null*.  you know in logical AND chains, just one *false* or *null* makes whole expression be *null* or *false*.

Comment: that sounds like a bug rather than a feature. Are there any reasons why this is not considered a bug and fixed?